# How to locate the layout across view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, layout, frame

I have a menuView in a list view controller. The menuView added on the UITableViewCell when a more button in the cell being taped.
[image]
I achieved the effect with singleton.

```
@implementation ProductsOperationMenu
static ProductsOperationMenu *_instance;
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[self alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    });
    return _instance;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**ZBMyProductsCell.m**

```
@implementation ZBMyProductsCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    _operationMenu = [[ProductsOperationMenu alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
}

- (IBAction)operationButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self.contentView.subviews containsObject:_operationMenu]) {
        _operationMenu.hidden = ![_operationMenu isHidden];
    } else{
        [self.contentView addSubview:_operationMenu];
        _operationMenu.hidden = NO;
    }

    [_operationMenu mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(205);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(60);
        make.bottom.mas_equalTo(self.operationButton).offset(0);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(self.operationButton.mas_left).offset(-10);
    }];
}
```

Without Singleton, it became this:

[image]

So the question come.

I want to put the menuView on the controller's view, because it is unique or hidden, which used to belong to the cell.

How to convert layout of the more button selected to the controller's view?
How to use the methods to calculate?

```
- convertPoint:toView:
- convertPoint:fromView:
......
```

I did it in a simple way. Here is the code:

```
- (void)clickOperationButtonOfProductsCell:(ZBMyProductsCell *)myProductsCell{
    NSUInteger * operationIndex = [self.myProductsTableView.visibleCells indexOfObject:myProductsCell];
    CGFloat originY = operationIndex.row * 110 + 50 + 40;
    CGRect originFrame = CGRectMake(KScreenWidth - 55, originY, 0, 60);
    CGRect finalFrame = CGRectMake(KScreenWidth - 260, originY, 205, 60);
    self.operationMenuView.frame = originFrame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.operationMenuView.frame = finalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {    }];
}
```

How to achieve it more adaptively?

Comment: Do you want to display menuView when click on more button and it should not be hidden when table will scroll ?

Comment: No . to use `UIScollViewDelegate` is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try it like this:

```
// here is your cell where the more button belongs to
@interface ZBMyProductsCell: UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^moreAction)(ZBMyProductsCell *cell);

@end

@implementation ZBMyProductsCell

- (void)_moreButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    !self.moreAction ?: self.moreAction(self);
}

@end

// here is your view controller where your table view belongs to
// this is a `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ZBMyProductsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ZBMyProductsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.moreAction = ^(ZBMyProductsCell *cell) {
        CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // write your own code to show/hide the menu
    };

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The answer is not expected. maybe u can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341041/how-to-achieve-the-effect-of-uitableviewcell-selection-by-clicking-a-button-in-u

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in each cell model called cellIndexpath and in cellForRow init it

```
 cell.cellIndexpath  = indexpath
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look of `UIPopoverPresnetationController` and see if it can do the job. It should be available on iPhone. Putting `menu view` on the `controller’view`will cause issue **when you scroll the table view**.

---

use

```
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setTargetRect:self.detaiLabel.frame inView:self];
```